# JQuery/PHP - Only showing a button for Administrator account

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web site which allows users to logon to a control panel that allows users to change content of the web site.

When creating the users you can set the account type: (PHP)

i.e. `UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1` full access

and `UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 0` part access

I have stopped access to certain pages by using a redirect as follows:

```
if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 0 {
    header("Locaction: webpage.php");
}
```

However on certain pages I am wanting to hide certain buttons so that users with `UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 0` can't use or see them.

I am just wondering what the best way to achieve this would be?

I know I can hide buttons in jQuery using `$('target').hide();` but how would I do this from a PHP function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to only show a button if `UserAccount::get_accounttype()` is equal to `1` then use:

```
if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1) {
    // button HTML here
}
```

I would be strongly apposed to hiding the buttons using jquery as they will still show up in the source code, and wouldn't hide until the page was loaded.

Comment: also: for each page that you hided the buttons, re-check use access because if by any way user know the URL then he can access it...

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of doing this. I am only wanting to hide a button which allows users to delete accounts using jQgrid on select tow.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, would like to point out that using the Alternate Syntax for PHP would be recommended here. *Never echo HTML using PHP unless absolutely necessary, which should be pretty much never.*

```
<?php if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1): ?>
    <button type="button">Go</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not hide buttons to provide security, since they are still availavle through some techniques, like for example chrome's source code browser. You'd better not even display the button:

```
if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1) {
  <input type="button" ... />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with CSS or JavaScript/jQuery.  That is not secure.  Do it in your PHP:

```
if (UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1 {
    echo '<button>Go</button>';
}
```

Then, when you handle the form on the server, double check that the user has full access.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple php condition.

```
<?php if(UserAccount::get_accounttype() == 1): ?>
<input type'button' />
<?php endif; ?>
```